# CodeIgniter site issue upon uploading it to live server

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, mysqli

I am a beginner in PHP and MVC, I just developed a project in CodeIgniter and it was complete and working superb on my local machine. So I registered a domain and uploaded my site to the live server and the exported the db by sql file, and there are were a ton of problems that I faced, and I am still stuck.

It Won't accept the database information from the config file **'database.php'**, although it was correct, then I found out that I needed to set 'db_debug' to FALSE, so i did that and i changed the 'db_driver' from 'mysql' to 'mysqli' because of a deprecation error, and then had to comment out an elseif block in the `BASEPATH/system/database/drivers/mysqli/mysqli_driver.php` in the 'escape_str' function, and then that dear error was gone. And the site was running.

But as I tried to signup the is_unique validation rule wasn't working because it kept giving back the error, even when there was no such value in the db table, then I tried deleting that rule and then the form was submitted successfully but there were no entries made in the db. My guess is that the db connection is not being established.

I have loaded the 'database' library in the autoload.php.

Now the site is still working great on my local machine, and I can't figure out the problem.

Comment: Please be precise ... no one is gonna read your ESSAY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set db_debug to false, it just doesn't show the database errors, but doesn't actually solve anything. Actually it was a newly registered domain, so it took some time to assign the user to the db, i guess. because when I tried again after a few hours, The database connection succeeded, and it is working great.